# Include path not changing when I updated php.ini

Tags: php

I've run the following to determine which php.ini file is being used - `php -i | grep 'Configuration file'`.

I've then updated that php.ini file with the following - `include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/local/bin`

Then I restarted apache. But when I run a php script with the content - `<?php var_dump(include 'non/existant/file.php');` it tells me the following:

```
Warning: include(non/existant/file.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/debug_phpunit.php on line 3 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'non/existant/file.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/debug_phpunit.php on line 3 bool(false)
```

Notice the include path in the error message. My changes aren't there. Am I changing the wrong file? Could another configuration file be overwriting this?

Comment: The `php -i` command shows the config file for the CLI version of PHP, not the webserver version. Try running `phpinfo()` in a web page.